# How to delete all records except one record remaining?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, axios

I calling all ids with **getIds** function and use it in **clearSales** function.**clearSales** function is running at the end of the test .When I call **clearSales** all records deleted. I don't want all records deleted, only one record should remain. How to delete all records except one record according to below function?

```
const getIds= async () => {
    let res = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: '/v1/sales'
    })
    expect(res.status).toBe(200)
    const ids = [];
    res.data.salesId.forEach(item => {
        ids.push(item.id);
    });
    return ids
};

export const clearSales = async () => {
    const idList = await getIds()
    let res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/v1/feed/bulk_update',
        data: { "feed_ids": idList, "operation": "delete" },
    })
    expect(res.status).toBe(200)
};
```

Comment: You exclude the id you don't want to delete in the `getIds` function, or take it out of idList afterward in `clearSales`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply delete the id of the record you want to keep from `idList`. Here an example of implementation:

```js
export const clearAllOtherSales = async (remainingRecordId) => {
    let idList = await getIds();
    let index = idList.findIndex(id => id === remainingRecordId);
    if (index > -1) idList.splice(index, 1);
    let res = await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/v1/feed/bulk_update',
        data: { "feed_ids": idList, "operation": "delete" },
    });
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
}
```

`clearAllOtherSales(115)` clear all sales except the one with id 115.

Comment: thanks but here The number of recordingId can be changeable,it comes from UI . So I took the all ids and delete them except one